# InfluxQL Data source connection error "xxxxxx...." Database not found

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm using Grafana Cloud and Influxdb Cloud - free version

I'm trying to connect to Influxdb via Grafana (Influxdb) plugin

When creating connection it says - Connection successful but when I use it in panel or in query it doesn't work and throws error "Database not found"

I dropped the connection several times and recreated but same issue...

I particularly wanted to try the InfluxQL so that I can leveral my TSQL skills... so the drill

Appreciate the help...

[image]

Panel Error: Database not found
[image]

Comment: `Database not found` is self-explanatory. You have something wrong, e.g. typo in the DB name (maybe some white characters was added to the end during copy/paste) or URL is wrong (so DB can be right, it just sits on another server), .... Nobody will be able give you answer. Go to CLI and test your connection with influxdb CLI command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I resolved it ... [Link](https://medium.com/@ivanahuckova/setting-up-influxdb-v2-flux-with-influxql-in-grafana-926599a19eeb)

I first setup InfluxQL and then autheticated it via GitBash.

Tick is to use Token with the token key...

Hope this helps [someone](https://community.grafana.com/t/integration-with-influxdb-influxql-error-badrequest/42987/14)